# How do I use TF-IDF for set of keywords?

Tags: python, text-classification, tfidf

I have a set of keyword

> K = {K1,K2,K3,...}

> K1 = (president governor) k2 = (foot ball players goal) K3=(Hero Heroine song singer)

etc. like these

and each K1...Kn belongs to some category like in above k1- politics,K2-sports,K3-movies like a ML data set.
Now how can I use TF-IDF to convert these into a dataset like (train_x,Train_y) and(test_x,test_y)
I was Seeing that TF-IDF uses whole documents and extracting its own keywords but I already have the key words extracted,so how can I use TF-IDF now?, What technique I can use to convert this data into vectorized format so that I can use for classifying or training? I am using Python if any reference are there.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Your question is not very clear: what would be the job of the final classifier? would it have to classify new sets of keywords, i.e. to predict one of the existing categories for different keywords? About TFIDF, do keywords appear multiple times? If not (or rarely), then there's no point using TFIDF because it relies on frequency. The goal of TFIDF is give less weight to words like 'the' or 'a' (which are very frequent) compared to words like 'governor' or 'football' (less frequent).

Comment: If the goal is to classify actual text documents based on keywords, then you shouldn't use any ML but simple search.